# how to interpret estimates from survreg as it returns 1 variable less than input

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am using `survreg` in R's survival package to compare 5 species life span in an experiment. The survreg return this:

survreg(formula = Surv(time, time2, type = "interval2") ~ strain + 
    symbiosis, data = int)
`$
              Value Std. Error       z         p
(Intercept)  1.6645     0.0451  36.921 2.15e-298
strain1      0.8317     0.0910   9.140  6.23e-20
strain2     -1.5525     0.0921 -16.861  8.67e-64
strain3     -0.0319     0.0829  -0.385  7.00e-01
strain4     -0.5693     0.0831  -6.854  7.17e-12
symbiosis1   0.0000     0.0000     NaN       NaN
Log(scale)  -0.8095     0.0787 -10.285  8.22e-25`

My question is: Since there are 5 strains and it only returns 4, which one is the one that these four are compared to (as a baseline maybe?)? In addition, the data I input shows strain names, and from the result  I can't tell which is which. How could I know strain1 refers to which original strain I have?

Comment: What does `levels(int$strain)` return? The first value you see should be the reference level for factors with default contrasts.

Comment: Generally regression with factors as covariates use the Intercept to "report" the estimate for the lowest factor level. As MrFlick says, ... need levels. I'm guessing that you have a strain=0 level and perhaps cases mostly symbiosis=0 levels. The cases with symbiosis=1 are "aliased". In that case the `(Intercept)` would be the estimate for cases with both strain and symbiosis =0. I am left wondering what happened to the event variable? Perhaps you would get more comprehensible results if you instead used `+factor(strain)`?

Comment: It's weird than I re-wrote the code and now it shows  strain names. And the first strain in the data is the one missing. However, when I tried the levels function, it returns null.